# Display encoded image data in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting encode image data in response from api like this

[image]

i want to display this image data using angular, i tried to bind same in image tag but that didn't work

Any solution to display the image.

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like encoded image data. From an API that includes an image file in the response I would expect it to either return a link to the image or Base64 encoded data-uri. Either of which you could easily just use as the `src` attribute.

Comment: Can I ask, what is that screenshot from? Is it JSON?

Comment: @phuzi Yes it is JSON